# Using Lens, how do you compose setter with another function g such that the output of g is the new value to be set?

Tags: haskell

Simple example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Control.Lens

data Point = P { _x :: Double, _y :: Double } deriving (Show)
$( makeLenses ''Point )
```

This is what I am trying to do in imperative style:

```
point.set( "x", g (point.get("x") ) )
```

Currently I tried this implementation:

```
mapF f p g = let v = g (p ^. f) in set f v p
```

It's not an actual composition, not idiomatic, and also throws an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Mutator b0'
            with actual type `Accessor a0 a0'
Expected type: ASetter s1 t0 a0 b0
  Actual type: Getting a0 s0 a0
```

Even though a non-parameterized version of the above would work:

```
mapX p g = let v = g (p^.x) in set x v p
```

It seems like f could either be a getter or setter, not both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `over` function, whose type specializes in this case to:

```
over :: Setter a b -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
```

So you would just write:

```
over x :: (Double -> Double) -> Point -> Point
```